# Access request.user in Django Classed Based Generic View

Tags: django, generics, django-class-based-views

How can I access request.user inside a Classed Based Generic View?

This is the code:

```
class TodayView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "times/today.html"
    if Records.objects.all().count() > 0:
        last_record = Records.objects.latest('id')
    else:
        last_record = None
    actual_time = datetime.today()
    activities = Activity.objects.filter(owner=request.user)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TodayView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["today"] = self.actual_time

        return context
```

Right now, I get the error "request is not defined", if I write "self.request.user", I get "self" is not defined, which is understandable. I can think of a couple of ways to solve this but I want to know if there is a standardized/consensus on how to access request.user on Django Classed Based Generic Views.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that you should not be putting code at class level. All that code after `template_name` will be executed when the class is defined, not when the view is called. Not only is `self` and `request` not defined at that point, but also `today()` will be fixed at process startup.

All that code belongs inside `get_context_data`, from where you can do `self.request.user`.

Answer (score 4):

You can access the request in a Class based view at `self.request`.

So to get the user you'd use:

```
self.request.user
```