# Filter list of objects by self.request.user in Django

Tags: python, django, class, view, request

I cannot get this to work:

```
class MyView(generic.ListView):
    context_object_name = 'my-model-list'
    template_name = 'my_models.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return MyModel.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

I have also tried

```
return MyModel.objects.filter(user=User.objects.filter(name=self.request.user))
```

It seems that self.request.user is returning a name. The error I get is

```
Cannot query "a": Must be "User" instance.
```

The user's name is "a".

My model is

```
from .models import User

class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What output does `print(type(self.request.user))` and `print(self.request.user)` give you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access request.user in Django Classed Based Generic View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27072123/access-request-user-in-django-classed-based-generic-view)

Comment: the output I get is: 
    `<class 'django.utils.functional.SimpleLazyObject'>`
     `a`

Also I don't think this is a duplicate of that because the answer to that was that code cannot be at the class level, and my code is not at the class level.

Comment: How are you importing User and defining  auth in your settings? I have code that looks identical to yours working and my type output is `django.contrib.auth.models.User`.

Comment: `from .models import User` and `from django.contrib.auth import authenticate` at top of views.py
`@python_2_unicode_compatible
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    join_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name` in models.py

Comment: import user this way   ```from django.contrib.auth.models import User``` and try it again

Comment: I get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code as shown is correct. The problem is that you are defining your own User class and Django does not know how to handle it when making requests.

The easiest way to do this would be to use the Django User. If you insist on using your own User Class you will need to modify that class to properly inherit from the Django User and a few other things (there are a few StackOverflows on that).

In your ./MyModel/models.py you will want to import User as such:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

Leave your other models and your views as is (unless they also import User).

You may also have to update your settings file to look something like this (This may not be fully correct):

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    )
```

Don't forget to migrate your DB after making these changes.

Comment: I fixed the problem by creating my own separate User class called Person that uses a OneToOne relationship with User. Thank you everyone here for your help. 

`from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

Answer (score 2):

you are inheriting the User model the wrong way.
Use `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` instead.

Answer (score 1):

> You can use self.request.user.mymodel_set.all() to get all Querys of current user

```
from .models import User

class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)


class MyView(generic.ListView):
    context_object_name = 'my-model-list'
    template_name = 'my_models.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.request.user.mymodel_set.all()
```

Comment: Code-only answers can be unhelpful, consider editing your answer to explain what your code does and how it relates to the question